# disable web security on mobile browser ios

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, security, google-chrome

I have been searching around for a bit and cant find any solution to this question.

I need to run a browser on an iPAD that allows cross-origin policy to be bypassed. This is easily achieved with a windows machine by launching lets say chrome with `--disable-web-security` I have read that Phonegap allows this but the app is already in place.

Ill take any solution including jailbreak's

Comment: If you want this to get around the same origin policy, it might be easier to set up a proxy server, so it looks to the iOS device that all resources are coming from that same server.

Comment: Maybe if you explain your use case, we can come up with an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any official ways to do this.

If you rely on cookies, the alternative would be to read every header to every response and manually assign received cookies to different domains (the downside to this is that you must know the other domains to be used beforehand). For handling cookies, check out `[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage]`, the default storage for native apps.

Comment: I am also facing same problem in android device. I want to disable web security in chrome of android 4.4.2 device. can you suggest any solution?